# What is the recommended way to validate an address form field on Android?

Tags: android, forms, validation

I see that `TextView` has an inputType of `"textPostalAddress"`.They show this example in the documentation [(http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html)).

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/postal_address"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="@string/postal_address_hint"
android:inputType="textPostalAddress|
                   textCapWords|
                   textNoSuggestions" />
```

I can't find anything that explains the recommended way to validate this type of field.I know how to use `TextWatcher` to know when to validate.  I'm asking how to actually validate an address.

My concern is with the variances in address formats due to the user's location in the world.  I was hoping that Google anticipated this complexity and provided something for developers to use.

If there isn't a validator for it, then what good is it?  From my testing, it doesn't change the field in any noticeable way.

Comment: each country may have different rules as to what is a valid address.  What are you business rules surrounding this?

Comment: check this http://code.google.com/p/libaddressinput/wiki/AddressValidationMetadata

Comment: So what is the purpose of using the "textPostalAddress" inputType?  I can't see any difference between it and just using "text".